# ADO.Net Data Service Operation: Array of integers as a parameter

Tags: silverlight, wcf-data-services, wcf-ria-services

This question is a bit of a two parter for .Net data services.  This is the function signature I'm trying to achieve:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns Descriptions for any asset in the given assetIDs.
/// </summary>
[WebGet]
public IQueryable<Description> FindDescriptionForAssets(int[] assetIDs);
```

1. I'm trying to create a custom service operation on a ADO.Net Data Service that takes an array of integers as a parameter.  My understanding is that ADO.Net Data Services can't accept an array (or List or other enumerable) as a parameter.  Is this true?  Is there any way around it?
2. It looks using arrays like this may be achievable by using the .Net RIA Services's DomainService.  However, I haven't been able to find any examples demonstrating it.  Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: I found out that RIA services don't support inheritance currently (I really hope that is changed in the next release), so it turned out that wasn't an option.

I ended up creating a service operation for the ADO.Net Data Service, and instead of an array of ints, the IDs get passed in as comma separated values in a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RIA Services supports passing an array of integers. Just tested it out using this service call.

```
[ServiceOperation]
public string SayHello(int[] input)
{
    StringBuilder strings = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var i in input)
    {
        strings.AppendFormat("Hello {0}!", i);
    }

    return strings.ToString();
}
```

Not sure on the ADO.Net Data Service. Might be an issue because of the RESTful interface.